User‘s language settings lead to error in working with Excel programmatically
Is there a way to change the language of an Excel application/workbook during the execution of a function? The problem I face is the following:
In my organization there’s of course a lot of work that has to be shown in excel tables. We have functions (written in APL) that do most of the calculations and the result is then exported to an Excel sheet. We now face the problem that our code‘s functionality depends on the language settings of the user as we get errors in the following example.
Let's say we want to put the value 1 in the ranges A1:B2 and A5:B10, and we do that in one command
ActiveSheet.Range[⊂'A1:B2;A5:B10'].Value2←1
This works fine if Excel is in German but after I switched my Excel to English I got an error. The problem is the semicolon ";" that there is in the code which was written with German settings in mind. When I change that to a comma
ActiveSheet.Range[⊂'A1:B2,A5:B10'].Value2←1
I manage to get it work in English but not in German.
So my question is the following: Is it possible to get and set Excel's language in the function? If it is not German then I switch it to English, do my work, and in the end switch it back to whatever it was.
I wrote the example in APL as it is the one we use but a solution in other language (e.g. VB) would be fine as I guess it is more of an Excel question.

Getting the language is easy, as Michal mentioned. But you can skip a few steps, as you don't really want to know the language but only the list separator (and maybe decimal separator and a few others):
Dim delimiter As String
delimiter = Application.International(xlListSeparator)

This will work for any language, so you don't need to check for German, Dutch etc. Similarly, you can get other regional settings like xlDecimalSeparator. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international for the full list.
Setting the language or the list separator is more difficult. However, there is a trick to get consistent behaviour: setting the decimal separator to "," will force the list separator to be ";", if it was a "," in the current language.
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
Application.DecimalSeparator = "," 

This may not be the setting you want, but at least it is consistent so you can modify your source files accordingly.

That solves the problem in a universal way, which is good, because it might be that someone else prefers a third language and then it becomes chaotic. The only problem is that we must collect all the differences and modify our code accordingly which is of course doable but painful :D Anyway it solves my problem so I’ll wait a couple of days in case some other answer comes which takes care of all the possible differences there may be and not only the separator, otherwise I’ll accept it as an answer

VBA is US-centric. As such, the list separator in VBA will always be the comma.
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2,A5:B10").Value = 1

in VBA will fill those cells with 1 no matter the language.
Range("A1").Formula = "=average(B2:C10, D2:D10)"

will place the formula in A1 with the correct separator.
A1: =AVERAGE(B2:C10; D2:D10)

You may have an issue if you are writing formulas to the worksheet that make use of the TEXT function with tokens for month, day and year, but that should be handled differently. Let me know if that is the case.
Also, any formulas that are used in Conditional Formatting  will need to be translated into the local language. This translation can be done by writing the formula to a worksheet cell, then reading it back using the .FormulaLocal property of the Range object.

Ok good to know that VBA is consistent with that and does not depend on the language. So the problem appears only through APL (or possibly other languages as well), which makes me wonder what the mechanism behind this connection is, but ok that’s a different and bigger topic. BTW I actually do not need formulas, everything is done in APL and the excel really comes at the end: just take a bunch of raw numbers and put them in that range

It's doable but it's a pain with a lot of caveats.  For VBA you would have to use something like:
Dim delimiter As String

' Determine the delimiter based on the Excel language
If Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI) = 1031 Then
    ' German Excel
    delimiter = ";"
Else
    ' Default to English (or other languages that use commas)
    delimiter = ","
End If

and that's just the beginning of it.  I think you are about to have a lot of fun.  Enjoy.

The question is tagged with VB.Net which is not the same as VBA

@Blackcat I've read the actual question which says "I wrote the example in APL as it is the one we use but a solution in other language (e.g. VB) would be fine as I guess it is more of an Excel question."

That would work but it solves only the special case of semicolon in the range. I actually do not know all the differences there might be that’s why I said maybe I should switch the language for a while.

@Michal I am ok with VBA, as I said we use APL but a solution in another language is a good start. I added vb.net because I thought people from that world might know something about it, and also I could translate it easier to APL
